# Power empty android (Samsung) - cannot charge

Tags: samsung, charging

Samsung SM-T580 power became empty and stopped. Connection with charger result in flickering (black) screen with the charge icon showing. I used several cables and adapter. After many hours the tablet still does not power up.

Comment: try to press vol down + home + power

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect it from the charger. Press the power button for 60 seconds and let go. Now connect the charger. Again press the power button for 30 seconds. This way usually works with tabs.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but no, it did not work. I read this and tried several times.,